# Moderator spam flag fails on ownerless posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools, spam

I just tried to spam flag a post out of existence on Biology (https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/9132/6), but I only got the message that an error was encountered while flagging and the post was not deleted. However, the post score was reduced by 1 as expected. I deleted it now manually, but spam flagging usually works to remove a post. The one thing that was different in this case is that the user owning the spam post was already removed.

There might be another connected bug, as I strongly suspect that the deleted user was the cross-site spammer that was nuked by an SE employee network-wide yesterday. So that post should not have remained but deleted along with all the other posts belonging to the spammer.

Comment: Note, I did a network wide _deletion_, which would not have deleted zero scored posts. _Derp, probably should have checked that first ..._

Comment: I assumed it was a network-wide destroy. It took a while to find this leftover spam post, as it just looks like a community-bumped question and probably also was removed from the review queues.

Comment: I'm not a moderator, but it seems to me that there is no reason to spam-flag an ownerless post. The spam flag is really used for the 100-rep penalty, right? You can't give Community a 100-rep penalty. It should at least kill the post, though...

Comment: @Undo Lock and delete. Prevents undeletion by non-mods.

Comment: Also force of habit.

Comment: So a mod *can* make a post that even he can't spam-nuke!

Comment: @Manishearth Just plain deleting prevents non-mod undeletion.

Comment: @Kevin Hm, forgot that. Prevents edits then (from bumping the post).

Comment: @Manish Can you edit a deleted post?

Comment: @Undo Well, the owner of the deleted post can. And moderators. Not sure about non-mods.

Comment: Flagging as spam will also ensure that the "this post has been removed" notice appears instead of the spam so 10K (4K on beta sites) users don't have to see it.

Comment: Any user can edit a deleted post as long as it is visible to them and it is not locked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this just rolled out, sorry we didn't notice it sooner.  It was attempting to relate the flags with the spam rep penalty, which doesn't exist if there's no user to penalize.